# WMI Filter in Group Policy evaluating incorrectly

Tags: group-policy, wmi

I have three machines: 
ASAAD-0 
MSN-LEED01 
MSN-LEED02

In group policy I have a WMI filter called LEED which is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE (Name != "MSN-LEED01" OR Name != "MSN-LEED02")
```

The OU that contains the GPO with this filter is being applied to all three machines.

On ASAAD-0 when I run gpresult /h I can see that this filter evaluates to True, which is expected. However, on both of the LEED machines it still evaluates to True, while it seems it should be evaluating to False.

I've tried a few different ways to verify Win32_ComputerSystem.Name is the correct value.

If I hop on, say, MSN-LEED02 and run the Powershell command `Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem` it returns a few fields, and the Name field is indeed MSN-LEED02.

[Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH4Lt.png)

However, if I open up wbemtest, go into Enum Classes, and find Win32_ComputerSystem and look at its properties, the Name value is null.

[wbemtest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIeRF.png)

The last thing I tried was using [this](https://sdmsoftware.com/389932-gpo-freeware-downloads/wmi-filter-validation-utility/) third party tool to test the filter from above. Both MSN-LEED01 and MSN-LEED02 return true even though, for example, (Name != MSN-LEED01) should be false since the name seems to be equal to MSN-LEED01.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong with the filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the "OR" by "AND" in your query :

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem WHERE (Name != "MSN-LEED01" AND Name != "MSN-LEED02")
```

However, you can just add the computers (or an AD security group  containing these computers) in the "Delegation" tab in the Group Policy management, and Deny "Apply Group Policy", (and deny "Read" too if you want to prevent these computers to apply the "User" settings of the group policy), it's more efficient than a WMI Filter and easier to maintain.

Comment: Changing the AND or using the Delegation both work. Thank you!